# Summarise column based on contents of other column

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to write a code that compares two columns in the same dataframe, using the summarise to create a new column that will state if the ID was registered before the Review took place.

This is my dataframe:

```
tt <- structure(list(ID = c("P40", "P40", "P40", "P42", "P42", "P43", "P43",
                      "P44", "P44"),Type = c("Pre-Initial", "Review", "Review", "Initial", "Review", "Initial", "Review", "Pre-Initial", "Review"),
               Registered = c("Yes", "", "", "No", "", "Yes", "", "No", "")),
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Result I want to achieve:

```
ID  Outcome
P40 Yes
P42 No
P43 Yes
P44 No
```

This is the code I have tried but only shows No for all IDs

```
tt %>% group_by(ID) %>%
    summarise(outcome = c("No", "Yes")[all(Registered == "Yes" & Type == "Review") + 1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could try:

```
tt %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(
    Outcome = c("No", "Yes")[any(Type == "Review" & cumsum(Registered == "Yes") == 1) + 1]
  )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  ID    Outcome
  <chr> <chr>  
1 P40   Yes    
2 P42   No     
3 P43   Yes    
4 P44   No
```

Note that this assumes the `Yes` for `Registered` occurs exactly once per each `ID`. Otherwise just replace `cumsum(Registered == "Yes") == 1` with `cumsum(Registered == "Yes") >= 1`.

Comment: Thank you, but whne I tried your code but I am getting NA variables for all IDs

Comment: Have you tried it on your example? For me it works with your `dput`. Otherwise try to enhance the example you've provided so that it is more similar to what you have.

Comment: That's good to hear! Consider accepting the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 2):

Another `dplyr` variant, here it returns `"No"` if there is no value in `Registered` as `"Yes"` or it compares the index of occurrence of it and `"Review"` and assign values accordingly.

```
library(dplyr)

tt %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(Outcome = if (any(Registered == "Yes")) 
      c("No", "Yes")[(which.max(Registered == "Yes") < 
                     which.max(Type == "Review"))+1] else "No")

#  ID    Outcome
#  <chr> <chr>  
#1 P40   Yes    
#2 P42   No     
#3 P43   Yes    
#4 P44   No
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but when I try the code I get an error stating "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Comment: I have fixed the error, added !is.na in the if: !is.na(any(Registered == "Yes"))

Comment: @NartRazak There is also `na.rm` parameter in `any` so you can do `any(Registered == "Yes", na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: That seems more better option

Answer (score 0):

I’m not exactly sure what your intended result is but from your description it sounds as if the `Type == 'Review'` rows are simply irrelevant: All you need is to remove them, and then remove that column (and rename the `Registered` column):

```
tt %>%
    filter(Type != 'Review') %>%
    select(- Type, Outcome = Registered)
```